# Question about functions of class $C^1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, partial-derivative

Firstly, I apologize by the generic and poor title of this topic, but I don't know what to put in the title.

> $\textbf{Question:} \ $Let be $f: \mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function that have all directional derivatives in each point of $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} (u) > 0$ for each $u \in S^{n-1}$, prove that exists $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} (a) = 0$ for each $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I would like to receive a hint, because I don't have idea how to start it.

Thanks in advance!

> $\textbf{EDIT:}$
>
> My attempt after receive the hint of dbx:
>
> Firstly, I realized that the result of the question for case $n = 1$ go straight of Darboux's theorem taking $a = -1$, $b = 1$ and $d = 0$:
>
> $\textbf{Darboux's theorem}:$ let be $f: [a,b] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ differentiable. If $f'(a) < d < f'(b)$, then exists $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f'(c) = d$.
>
> For the geral case, we define $g: [0,1] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ by $g(t) := (u)t + (1-t)(-u)$ where $u \in S^1$ and consequently $-u \in S^1$.
>
> We observe that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} (-u) < 0$ because $\frac{\partial f}{\partial (-u)} (-u) > 0$ by hypothesis and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial (-u)} (-u) = -\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} (-u) > 0 \Longrightarrow \frac{\partial f}{\partial u} (-u) < 0$.
>
> Thus, $f \ \circ g: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $\frac{d(f \ \circ g)}{dt} (0) = f'(g(0)) \cdot g'(0) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u} (-u) \cdot 2u < 0$, $\frac{d(f \ \circ g)}{dt} (1) = f'(g(1)) \cdot g'(1) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u} (u) \cdot 2u > 0$ and, by Darboux's theorem, exists $c \in (0,1)$ such that $\frac{d(f \ \circ \ g)}{dt} (c) = 0$, then $\frac{d(f \ \circ \ g)}{dt} (c) = f'(g(c)) \cdot g'(c) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u} (g(c)) \cdot 2u = 0$ (*). Since $u \in S^1$, $u \neq 0$, therefore, $(*)$ imply that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} (g(c)) = 0$, then exists $g(c) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} (g(c)) = 0$, but how can I show that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} (g(c)) = 0$ for each direction $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Take a point $a$ in the closed unit ball where $f$ assumes the minimal value on the ball. Can $a$ be on the boundary?

Answer (score 2):

Consider $n=1$. Here the statement is equivalent to: the differentiable function $f$ satisfies $f'(1)>0$ and $f'(-1)<0$. Prove that $f'(a)=0$ for some point in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I edited my post. Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1):

Since your function is strictly increasing as it leaves the (bounded) region bounded by the $n-1$ unit sphere then how small will it get inside this region?